# XMLHttpRequest cannot load AngularJS post request returns 302

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I do a request from curl it works, but when I try to do the same thing from AngularJS it returns:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/oauth/token
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

This is the curl query:

`curl -v https://www.example.com/oauth/token -d "client_id=1&client_secret=1&code=1"`

This is my AngularJS code:

```
                 $http({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "https://www.example.com/oauth/token",
                        data: "client_id=" + clientID + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&code=" + requestToken,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                        }
                    })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        //  deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status) {
                        console.log(data);
                        //deferred.reject("Problem authenticating");
                    })
                    .finally(function () {
                        //                  setTimeout(function () {
                        //                      browserRef.close();
                        //                  }, 10);
                    });
```

What can be the problem?

**Also, I tried all the solution from the possible duplicate page, and they didn't work.**

I tried to do the request on a local nodejs webserver and it returns the result. From the client I make the request to the nodejs webserver, and I have the same issue, even though the request is on http.

Comment: Did you read the error message, it's pretty clear. For whatever reason, the  preflight is getting a redirect response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my $.ajax showing "preflight is invalid redirect error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645511/why-my-ajax-showing-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-error)

Comment: If you don't control the remote domain you will need to use a  proxy on your server or third party service. Secret keys should be kept secret anyway

Comment: I understand this, but can you please elaborate on how to approach this issue in my case?

Comment: curl is command line, so you are not sending your request against a registered domain. If you did register your domain with the provider, you need to make your request on the domain..

Comment: I did register the domain with the provider

Comment: but your curl request is coming from curl. that's not a domain request, it's a command line request with no domain, and not a secure request. another problem is https cannot be queried by non-https client. Again, curl command line is not being sent from secure client. This must be done from your domain client in https

Comment: I understand that, how can I do it in angularjs

Comment: make the same request with http call. make sure your client is in SSL

Comment: Right, can you please point me on how to do that from my angularjs client